# print dataframe in console with rowbreaks

Tags: r

I have a long dataframe with 1000+ observations I want to print column-wise to fit screen in console. Se example below:

Looks likes this now:

```
A tibble: 20 x 1

   NAME 

   < chr >

 1 aa   
 2 bb   
 3 cc   
 4 dd   
 5 ee   
 6 ff   
 7 gg   
 8 hh   
 9 ii   
10 jj   
11 kk   
12 ll   
13 mm   
14 nn   
15 oo   
16 pp   
17 qq   
18 rr   
19 ss   
20 tt
```

Want it to look like this:

```
   NAME 

   < chr >

 1 aa        ff       ll      rr
 2 bb        gg       mm      ss
 3 cc        hh       nn      tt
 4 dd        ii       oo
 5 ee        jj       pp
 6 ff        kk       qq
```

Is that doable? :)

Best wishes,
H

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/formatting.html

Comment: Thanks but not quite what I was looking for